# Common mutex for shared library dynamic loading and thread_local initialization?

Tags: c++, gcc, thread-local, dynamic-loading

In the GCC C/C++ runtime for Linux, is there a mutex that is locked during both shared library dynamic loading (with **dlopen()**) and the initialization of a **thread_local** variable?  If the **thread_local** variable is declared within a function, it seems like this mutex is locked   whenever the initialization point of the variable is traversed during execution.  (Presumably to check whether the variable has already been initialized.)  In **dlopen()**, this mutex seems to be locked during dynamic initialization of non-locals in the shared library.

This is an example of a call (from a gdb backtrace) which (I think) is locking the mutex, in order to do initialization of a **thread_local** variable (or check if it was already initialized).

```
#4  0x00007ffbf6560daa in __cxa_thread_atexit_impl (func=<optimized out>, obj=0x7ffbf52646a0, dso_symbol=0xd48008) at cxa_thread_atexit_impl.c:117
117       __rtld_lock_lock_recursive (GL(dl_load_lock));
```

Comment: But, doesn't your question answer itself?

Comment: I am asking if my inference that this mutex exists is correct.  Hopefully someone can also describe or point to documentation of accurate specifics of how it is used.

Comment: I think you can use `objdump` or `gdb` to disassemble a function of interest to see how it implements that initialization.

Comment: My assembler knowledge is very rusty.